# Understanding injection dependency in app and tests in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, dependency-injection, karma-runner

I have a dependency injection (understanding) problem while testing a directive (AjaxLoader displayed only when there is a pending request).

App declaration :

```
angular.module('app', [
    'directives.ajaxLoader',
    'services.httpRequestTracker',
    [...]
])
```

Directive code :

```
angular.module('directives.ajaxLoader', [])
.directive('ajaxLoader', ['httpRequestTracker',
    function(httpRequestTracker) {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'common/ajaxLoader.tpl.html',
            link: function($scope) { // This function can have more parameters after $scope, $element, $attrs, $controller
                $scope.hasPendingRequests = function() {
                    return httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests();
                };
            }
        };
    }
])
```

Test code :

```
describe('ajaxLoader', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('directives.ajaxLoader', 'common/ajaxLoader.tpl.html');
    });

    describe('ajaxLoader directive', function() {});
});
```

From there, my directive works perfectly well in the browser, but tests fails with an error like :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: httpRequestTrackerProvider
>   <- httpRequestTracker <- ajaxLoaderDirective

Ok, so I need to inject my dependency somewhere. I have two solutions :

- in my directive directly :

> ```
> angular.module('directives.ajaxLoader', [
>      'services.httpRequestTracker'
> ])
> ```

- in my test code directly :

> ```
> beforeEach(function() {
>      module('directives.ajaxLoader', 'common/ajaxLoader.tpl.html', 'services.httpRequestTracker');
> });
> ```

Both works, but I don't understand which one is the better **and why** ? And why is it working in my browser from the start and fails in my test ? In both case, all my directives and trackers are injected in my main app declaration

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loading modules**

It works in your application because `services.httpRequestTracker` is loaded. you did that by declaring it as a dependency of the main app module (your first code snippet).

However, when you test things, you want to mock everything that is not being tested to avoid biass. In your case, what if you had a problem in `services.httpRequestTracker`? `ajaxLoader` might be fine but your tests will fail.

**Mocking**

To mock everything else, you have two options:

- spies (e.g. this http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/introduction-to-unit-test-spies/ )
- use dependency injection to substitute components

To use a dependency, you have to load the module with `module()`.

you will have to load the dependency, but this might have a mock implementation.

**Dependency Injection**

Dependency injection lets you decouple classes. There is a service locator to resolve dependencies by name. That is, you say *attribute a of class C is of type 'animal'* (a string!). The service locator in the angular core finds which component implements it. A way of determining this is by looking up the loaded modules (e.g. dependencies of the main app module).

You didn't define any of this in your testing area (but it isn't a problem!). Karma uses a file `karma.conf` that contains a list of files to use. You might use this file to add libraries or mocked components.

**With your particular problem:**

The directive depends on `httpRequestTracker`. If you don't inject it there, it won't work (so it's ok).
In your test, you have to load both. That's why the first time it failed and the second it worked. However, instead of loading `httpRequestTracker`, I'd load a mock implementation of it.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and enlightning answer ;) So my first solution `in my directive directly` is totally to proscribe ? I must instead either provide a mock or inject explicitely it in my test ?

Comment: hey no prob! You should consider testing environment and app like two separate things. regarding the app: If you need something injected in your directive, go for it. if you inject it, it should probably be declared as a dependency of the module. now, regarding the tests: if you injected (past simple!) something in your directive, it should be mocked or spied to provide mock function answers.